# How to Stop Message Queue Service

Tags: java, ibm-mq, mq

I have wriiten startMQ method to process message from websphere message queue. Below is my code snippet.

```
void startMQ(){

    try { 
        // getting connection
        // getting session
        // getting queue

        for(; ;){
            // Processing every messages from queue
        }
    } catch (Exception e){

    } finally {
        // closing queue
        // closing session
        // closing connection
    }
}

public static void main(String arg[]){
    Listener l = new Listener();
    l.startMQ();    
}
```

From bat file i will call main method to start message queue.

if i want to stop this. How to acheive this. i thought in many ways but cannot able to implement it. Please help.

Comment: Yes i need to exit the problem with closing connection. just i need to stop the service.

Comment: 1), Send signal to process, 2) create socket and use it for communication, 3) via REST endpoint, etc ....

Comment: Consider using a `Runtime` `ShutdownHook` handler.

Answer (score 3):

After the queue is empty, the program will get an exception with `RC=2033` which means "No Message Available."  As it falls out of the `Catch` block and into the `Finally` block it should hit the close queue, close session, close connection.  That should do it, yeah? You may be over-thinking this one.